# Do a person get-out of / be out of / leave / exit balance?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

What is the idiomatic word to go with 'balance' in the following context?

For example:
If a person had one disease and then got another one, we might say "He had one disease, and as a result he **got out of /  was out of / left / exited** balance and got another one". (or maybe other choices I've not mentioned).

Comment: Sometimes we say that someone is [**off balance**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/off_balance).

Comment: _Out of balance_ is possible too (but I don't understand the connection with catching diseases!).

Comment: It's knwon that many times that one may get a secondary diseases due to imbalance caused by primary disease.

Comment: Is this something that helps? *The first disease compromised his immune system. He consequently contracted a second disease.*